# How can Hubot run function regularly, without any command?

Tags: hubot

I'm trying to make a function for hubot send a message every 5 minutes to a room without any command, just by himself.

```
module.exports = (robot, scripts) ->
  setTimeout () ->
    setInterval () ->
      msg.send "foo"
    , 5 * 60 * 1000
  , 5 * 60 * 1000
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use node-cron.

```
$ npm install --save cron time
```

And your script should look like this:

```
# Description:
#   Defines periodic executions

module.exports = (robot) ->
  cronJob = require('cron').CronJob
  tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'
  new cronJob('0 0 9 * * 1-5', workdaysNineAm, null, true, tz)
  new cronJob('0 */5 * * * *', everyFiveMinutes, null, true, tz)

  room = 12345678

  workdaysNineAm = ->
    robot.emit 'slave:command', 'wake everyone up', room

  everyFiveMinutes = ->
    robot.messageRoom room, 'I will nag you every 5 minutes'
```

More details: https://leanpub.com/automation-and-monitoring-with-hubot/read#leanpub-auto-periodic-task-execution

Answer (score 2):

Actually the [hubot documentation](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/docs/scripting.md) shows the usage of `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` without the use of extra modules.

You could even do it inline by binding onto the msg object.
For example this:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  updateId = null

  robot.respond /start/i, (msg) ->
      msg.update = () ->                        # this is your update
          console.log "updating"                # function

      if not this.updateId                      # and here it
          this.updateId = setInterval () ->     # gets
             msg.update()                       # periodically
          , 60*1000                             # triggered minutely
          msg.send("starting")
```

Comment: You still need to launch a first command, which is what the author wants to avoid, I think... But thank you for that alternative !

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you are trying to use `msg.send` without a message object. You should instead replace that line with a `robot.messageRoom` command (or some equivalent command if you want to send a private message).